# The probability function the number of of males in a family with $5$ people

Tags: probability

The probability to birth a male is $0.45$ , let $X$ be the number of of males in a family with $5$ people

> What is the probability function of $X$

My try

$$
\begin{array}{c|lcr}
 X&0&1&2&3&4&5 \\
\hline
\text{P}_\text{X}(x) & 0.55^5 & 0.45\times0.55^4 &0.45^2\times 0.55^3 &0.45^3\times0.55^2&0.45^4\times0.55&0.45^5 \\
\end{array}
$$

But currently the sum is $<1$

Comment: you are leaving out the binomial coefficients $\binom 5X$

Comment: That depends on your assumptions about traditional marriage between one man and one woman, the likelihood of single parent families and the percentage of single parent families with a male vs. female parents and so on.

Comment: If the family "has five people", are the parents included in that?

Comment: "a group of 5 people"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One male can happen in five ways: $$MFFFF\\FMFFF\\FFMFF\\FFFMF\\FFFFM$$and each of them has probability $0.45\cdot0.55^4$ of happening. Two males and three males can happen in ten ways each, and four males can happen in five ways.